# Turing machine that adds 2-digit binary numbers

Tags: binary, computer-science, turing-machines

Hey as the title says am trying to create a Turing machine that adds 2 2-digit binary numbers.

Up till now I managed to make it work for the case of 10 + 01 but I can't make it work for all the number combinations. Could anyone help? This is my code so far.

The input format is X NUM1 NUM2 X NUM3 NUM4 (x10x01):

```
State Read Write Direction NextState
0 X X R 0
0 1 1 R 0
0 0 1 L 1
1 X 0 L 1
1 0 0 L 1
1 1 0 L 2
2 X 0 R 2
2 0 0 R 2
2 1 1 R 0
3 _ _ N HALT
```

Answer (score 0):

You TM does the following:

- State 0: move right until we read a 0, then write 1, move left and go to state 1.
- State 1: move left until we read a 1, then write 0, move right and go to state 2.
- State 2: move right until we read a 1, move right and go to state 0.
- State 3 (never reached): Halt

This logic doesn't appear to be adding anything. On input `x10x01` it will:

1. Tape: `x10x01`, state 0, head at position 1 (`x`). Move right until we read a 0, write 1, move left and go to state 1.
2. Tape: `x11x01`, state 1, head at position 2 (`1`). Move left until we read a 1, then write 0, move right and go to state 2.
3. Tape: `x01x01`, state 2, head at position 3 (`1`). Move right until we read a 1, move right and go to state 0.
4. Tape: `x01x01`, state 0, head at position 4 (`x`).
5. Tape: `x01x11`, state 1, head at position 4 (`x`).
6. Tape: `x00x11`, state 2, head at position 4 (`x`).
7. Tape: `x00x11`, state 0, head at position 6 (`1`). At this point the machine loops forever or crashes, depending on the specifics of your implementation, as it will read uninitialized tape.

While it might **look like** the machine added `01` and `10` to get `11`, really it just shuffled `1`s and `0`s around haphazardly.

An actual addition TM would need to do a few more things than your machine is doing. Specifically:

- Find the least significant unmarked bit of both operands,
- Mark them,
- Based on their values, determine the one-bit result and the one-bit carry
- Write the result, and apply the carry to the next least-significant unmarked bits.
- Repeat until there are no more digits.

Since you're only worried about two-digit numbers, you can skip marking the digits, and just have additional states to track which bit you're working with.

You could also just hard-code all possible inputs (there are only 16), but that's probably not in the spirit of the homework you've been assigned.

For example, to actually add two one-bit numbers, you might want an algorithm like this:

- State 0: move right until we read a digit. Write 0. If the digit is 0, go to state 1. If the digit is 1, go to state 2.
- State 1: move right until we read a digit. If the digit is 0, go to state 3. If the digit is 4, go to state 4.
- State 2: move right until we read a digit. If the digit is 0, go to state 4. If the digit is 5, go to state 5.
- State 3: write 0, halt
- State 4: write 1, halt
- State 5: write 1, move right go to state 3.

In this example, states 1 and 2 track whether the first number was 0 or 1. States 3, 4 and 5 add the numbers together. State 3 is when both are 0. State 4 is when one is 1. State 5 is when both are 1 (this has a carry).

The corresponding TM might look like this:

```
State Read Write Direction NewState
0 X X R 0
0 0 0 R 1
0 1 0 R 2
1 X X R 1
1 0 0 N 3
1 1 1 N 4
2 X X R 2
2 0 0 N 4
2 1 1 N 5
3 _ 0 N Halt
4 _ 1 N Halt
5 _ 1 R 3
```

I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to wire two iterations of this concept together to add two 2-bit numbers.